# how to install rawr?

Tags: jruby

I followed

http://rawr.rubyforge.org/

I typed rawr install but it says it couldn't find the package....

```
No command 'rawr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'raw' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'rar' from package 'rar' (multiverse)
rawr: command not found
```

am I supposed to run jruby -S rawr install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're probably on Ubuntu, based on the 'multiverse' reference. If you don't already have rubygems, then you should first do `sudo apt-get install rubygems` from a terminal. Then you should be able to install rawr with `sudo gem install rawr`.

The `rawr install` command is not actually for installing rawr itself. It's one of the commands that you can run *with* rawr to package your source files.

Also, there might be a .deb package for rawr in Ubuntu's repositories. You can check for one with something like `sudo apt-cache search rawr | grep ruby | more` or just `sudo apt-cache search rawr | more` if you don't want to filter for the word "ruby" in package names.

Comment: do I need to install it inside Jruby ? jruby -S gem install rawr

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not really sure on that, to be honest. You can always try it without installing from within JRuby to see if it works, and if it doesn't then you can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if rawr is deprecated?  If not, where's the official repository now?

[Ruby gems](http://RubyGems.org):

> **rawr**
>   0.1.0
>
> This gem has been yanked, but it is still available for download for
>   other gems that may have depended on it. For more information or if
>   you need to remove it permanently, please [click here](http://help.rubygems.org/faqs/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem).

The link doesn't explain anything about why rawr was yanked and not present on engin yard's rubydocs either.

Anyway you can go to: [Getting Started with rawr](http://www.neurogami.com/blog/getting-started-with-rawr.html) and install from [www.neurogami.com](http://www.neurogami.com).

```
jruby -S gem install  rawr --source http://gems.neurogami.com
```

Also there's a home page [rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/) on [ruby forge](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/) so the absence elsewhere is a mystery.

Hope that's helpful.